# Jboss 404 while restarting instead of custom error page

Tags: apache2, jboss

I'm running an Apache2 Webserver and a Jboss 6 behind it connected with mod_proxy.

When I stop the JBoss and open the website in the browser I get my custom 404 error page.

When I restart the JBoss again i get the default JBoss 404 Page instead (Only while the server is starting).

I set my error page with :

`ErrorDocument 404 /errordocument.html`

Why does Apache not show my custom error page while JBoss is starting?
And how can i change it?

Comment: That is because in some moment during jboss startup this is accepting http connections but the application deployed isn't available.

Comment: @FedericoSierra Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand why apache is not handling the error then.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem myself.

I had to add

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

in my apache config to make it work.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride